# differentially expressed genes in R

Tags: r

```
I have the matrix in the following format :


ID_REF      GSM362180    GSM362181  GSM362188    GSM362189  GSM362192
244901_at   5.094871713 4.626623079 4.554272515 4.748604391 4.759221647
244902_at   5.194528083 4.985930299 4.817426064 5.151654407 4.838741605
244903_at   5.412329253 5.352970877 5.06250609  5.305709079 8.365082403
244904_at   5.529220594 5.28134657  5.467445095 5.62968933  5.458388909
244905_at   5.024052699 4.714631878 4.792865831 4.843975286 4.657188246
244906_at   5.786557533 5.242403911 5.060605782 5.458148567 5.890061836
```

In the above matrix the first column is the list of genes ( 22810) and the corresponding columns correspond to the different promoters ( totally 4 different types) . How would it be possible to find the differentially expressed genes in such a case ??

I wantto use the t- test to identify the DEG's. I know to find the DEG's using the multtest package in R in case of two conditions ( such as control and treatment). But do not know how to proceed with four different types of promoters and identify the DEG's .

Comment: I see five columns, but you only mention four promoters. How many samples (or samples per promoter) do you have? Also, what is your question: are you looking for a general effect of promoters (whichever ones!)? Or do you want to create four lists of genes -- one for each promoter?

Comment: @ January: Actually there are totally 8 columns which has replicates of each promoter. SO totally there are 4 promoters ( with two replicates making it to eight columns). I wantto create a general list of promoters which are differentially expressed and also another list of the specific list of genes for each promoter. SO i would require both the possibilities .

Comment: Could I use limma package but am not sure how to do it or else should I use the ANOVA ??

Answer (score 2):

Use the `limma` package for all sorts of microarray differential expression. It has an excellent vignette, available (along with installation instructions) on its *Bioconductor* [landing page](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/limma.html). If using `limma`, follow up questions on the *Bioconductor* [mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/#bioconductor) (but please read the vignette and consult with someone with some statistical knowledge first, if necessary.